# How to add an element to the beginning when building a map()

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

```
enum StatusEnum {
  accepted = "AC",
  rejected = "RJ",
}
const select = (Object.keys(StatusEnum) as Array<keyof typeof StatusEnum>).map((x) => ({
  value: x,
  name: x + "_random",
}))
/**
 * Console.log(select)
 * [
 * 0: { value: "accepted" , name: "accepted_random" }
 * 1: { value: "rejected" , name: "rejected_random" }
 * ]
 */
```

How to beautifully add an object to the beginning of an array { value: "all" , name: "all_random" } ?

```
/**
 * Console.log(select)
 * [
 * 0: { value: "all" , name: "all_random" }
 * 1: { value: "accepted" , name: "accepted_random" }
 * 2: { value: "rejected" , name: "rejected_random" }
 * ]
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround it with an `array` and add the item at the beginning with `spread` operator for the `map` function.

```
const select = [{ value: "all" , name: "all_random" }, ...(Object.keys(StatusEnum) as Array<keyof typeof StatusEnum>).map((x) => ({
  value: x,
  name: x + "_random",
}))]
```

Comment: There's no need to use the spread operator for the first item. Just put the object as first element inside the other array.